# Best way to reconfigure a table so that it can be grouped by 2 columns simultaneously?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

EDIT: Thanks for all the responses so far, sorry my original question was so muddled. I'll try to clarify here...

Steve, I don't have the create information for the table, sorry. However, it looks something like this...

```
Activity_SerialNum - Student_ID - outdoors_date - indoors_date - video_game_date
000000001            222222222     6/5/15 16:30    
000000002            333333333                      6/5/15 15:00 
000000003            444444444     6/5/15 12:30
000000004            222222222                                      6/5/15 11:00          
000000005            333333333     6/5/15 9:00
000000006            222222222                      6/4/15 15:30
000000007            333333333                      6/4/15 12:00
000000008            444444444     6/4/15 16:00
000000009            222222222     6/4/16 9:00                                         
000000010            333333333                                      6/4/15 16:00
```

Where you can have multiple IDs doing multiple activities in any given day, and each time anyone does any kind of activity they create a new serial number in the table that's linked one student ID and at least one specific activity start date (though conceivably there could be instances where an activity serial number row has a student ID and an activity date in two or even all 3 activity date columns, like if they were indoors and outdoors on the same day). At the end of the day, I don't need the activity serial number.... all I need is a way to relate a specific student ID (that reappears often) with a tally of the number of times they participate in each activity, and to be able to break it down in a given month to see how activity participation changes for individuals or the group as a whole. I.e. "Student 333333333 logged activity of 17 indoors_dates and 14 video_game_dates in Jan of 2014, but in Feb of 2014 he logged 20 indoors_dates and 10 video_game_dates" but also "In Nov of 2014 there were a total of 240000 instances of outdoor activity (outdoors_dates), 400000 instances of indoor activity (indoors_dates and 350000 instances of video game activity (video_game_dates). I'm not interested in specific days or times of day, or duration (which I can't measure anyway since I just have the start time of the activity), Just in a tally of the number of times each student_id (and then the total # of students) participated in each activity, by month.

Thanks for the book and method suggestion Dan, I'll look into it. 
Anon, I agree on all counts... I'm humbled and a little disturbed by how much I don't know at this point, though I'm teaching myself as quickly as possible so hopefully that won't last forever. (Though FWIW I was just listing the sizes of the table and rows so no one would think I could just put it straight into excel to mess with it, since I'm pretty sure it's far far too big for excel).

Original Post: 
What I'm trying to do is to get a count of the number of times each individual in my table took part in one of 3 activities, per month. I need to create a table that best facilitates that (and then send that table to excel so that I can create a pivot table+chart that will allow people to look at overall activity participation trends by month, and then to look at activity participation trends per individual if they so choose... but Ideally I'd like to get SQL to do as much of the heavy lifting as possible).

I'm working in sql server 2008 r2, and let's say I'm tracking the activities of students to see what they're doing. My table consists of a varchar(16) Primary Key that is basically generated any time any student indicates that they took part in an activity (there are millions of these instances). Another varchar(255) row consisting of hundreds of thousands of 9 digit student IDs (these are unique to each student, but are replicated throughout the column because each student participates in multiple activities over the course of any given month... I didn't set them up to be 255, that happened before my time). Then 3 datetime rows, one for each activity (outdoors, indoors, video_games), that contain the start time of the activity they took part in that day.

And since I'm at the Everest part of the learning curve here, I'm struggling a bit. My first set of code didn't accomplish anything, really... just a ton of duplicates in the count, and nowhere near what I need in terms of being able to SEE what each student_id is doing each month if need be. (I deleted the original garbage code because I think it was so bad it was just more confusing)

So my question to you is, how do I proceed? I presume the best start would be making the table so that the student_id is the primary key? But even then I'm not sure how to go from there to a situation where I can get the table in a condition that it can be used to provide group AND student-level data, by month, in excel. I'm really open to any suggestions anyone has, I've been thinking on this for days and I keep running into a wall where I'm not sure where I'm being limited by my own skill and understanding of sql, and where I'm being limited by what sql is capable of (I presume most of my problem is the former). Is this even something I can do with just sql and standard excel? Do I need to start learning a bit of visual basic, and if so, can you point me in the direction of what kind of code I'll have to focus on there so I can start teaching myself?

Thanks in advance to anyone who reads and contributes, know that I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you give a sample of the input and output you expect?

Comment: Can you show the create table statements for student_activities table.

Comment: I suggest a normalized design which includes a many to many relationship between students and activities.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: How can a varchar(255) column contain hundreds of thousands of 9 digit student ids?

Comment: @SteveFord First row contains 000000001, second row contains 000000002, third one contains 000000003. Shall I go on? :)

Comment: Your opening paragraph is confusing. "count of the number of times each individual in my table took part in one of 3 activities" would suggest you would be better off doing a `GROUP BY student_id`. If you structure your `select` query correctly, you will then get each individual student id, with participation numbers by activity. Then in your Excel pivot table, you can use a `sum of` to show _total_ participation by activity

Comment: @DavidG that's what you are assuming, but it isn't clear from the description whether it's one table with 5 columns or whether its 3 tables. Where they mention rows do they mean columns e.g. "Another varchar row..." and "Then 3 datetime rows...."

Comment: @SteveFord On that one single point it's pretty clear to me! The rest of the question is pretty vague though.

Comment: You aren't going to run into "the limits of what sql is capable of" any time soon. Stop thinking in terms of rows. It's completely irrelevant how many rows or students or activities you have.  A correct solution for 5 students is a correct solution for 5 billion students. Think in terms of columns and how you want to manipulate those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what You need:

```
select year(up.[start_date]) [Year],month(up.[start_date]) [Month],up.Student_ID, up.activity, count(1) [count]
from activity_log l
unpivot (
[start_date] for [activity] in (outdoors_date, indoors_date, video_game_date)
) up
/*If You want just one month, then You can first filter just that month, and Youo don't need top group by year, and month*/
/*where year(up.[start_date])=2015
    and month(up.[start_date])=6*/
group by year(up.[start_date]),month(up.[start_date]), up.Student_ID, up.activity
```